# Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)

Tags: linux, virtualbox, debian

Been trying to install virtualbox on my Debian machine.
I'm running Debian bookworm.

I get this message when launching in terminal:

```
WARNING: The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module
     available for the current kernel (6.1.0-13-amd64) or it failed to
     load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by

       sudo /sbin/vboxconfig

     You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
```

Haven't tried anything yet (just reinstalling, and rebooting the system) I'm not an expert and don't want to break my system.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install make gcc build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r` dkms
```

i was with the same problem and fix with that,
worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Didn't seem to fix it...